# How to replace a text in a shell executable file (.sh) using Python?

Tags: shell-script, python

I have `xxx.sh` file which content is:

```
setsid ./start-meteor.sh >> /home/farah/StudioInstallation/Studio/bricks/platform/log/databricksastro.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

I want to change the above content to something like:

```
setsid ./start-meteor.sh >> /home/rose/validation/Studio/bricks/platform/log/databricksastro.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

I need a Python code to do so.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of this is giving you trouble? Why Python specifically?

Comment: Why don't you make the location of the output logfile a variable in the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your python script as any name as you like, say `search_replace.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
         line = re.sub('farah/StudioInstallation','rose/validation', line.rstrip())
         print(line)
```

run this script and pass your filename that is `xxx.sh` as an argument,

```
$python search_replace.py xxx.sh
```